# Unable to start elasticsearch 7.4.2 - error during startup

Tags: elasticsearch

I get the following error when starting up elasticsearch 7.4.2 on Windows 10 platform. I download the zip file, unzipped it and tried started it using  elasticsearch.bat. I also tried updating the elasticsearch.yml to change the port and host name, but nothing works. Could anyone help with this one? Thanks.

```
    [2019-11-30T00:26:06,319][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [ABHATIA-P51] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:125) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:78) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:73) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:60) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:134) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4Transport.doStart(SecurityNetty4Transport.java:81) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.doStart(SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:230) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:695) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:273) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:358) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:180) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:146) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:138) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:78) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:73) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:60) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:134) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4Transport.doStart(SecurityNetty4Transport.java:81) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.doStart(SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:230) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:695) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:273) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:358) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:94) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50) ~[?:?]
        at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:178) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:146) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:138) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:78) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:73) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:60) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:134) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4Transport.doStart(SecurityNetty4Transport.java:81) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.doStart(SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:230) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:695) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:273) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:358) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:732) ~[?:?]
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:194) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:127) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:76) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:61) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:171) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50) ~[?:?]
        at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:178) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:146) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:138) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:37) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:78) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:73) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:60) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:134) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4Transport.doStart(SecurityNetty4Transport.java:81) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.doStart(SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:230) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:695) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:273) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:358) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-7.4.2.jar:7.4.2]
        ... 6 more
```

Below is the content of the elasticsearch.yml file.

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: localhost
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 19300
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Comment: Can you paste your latest `elasticsearch.yml` content and also using this https://www.isunshare.com/blog/how-to-determine-what-ports-are-being-used-in-windows-10/ let me know port which you are specifying isn't being used

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal - I added the content of elasticsearch.yml file and also checked for port usage for port 19300, and it is not being used.
C:\Abh\Apps\elasticsearch-7.4.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.4.2\bin>netstat -ano | findstr 19300

C:\Abh\Apps\elasticsearch-7.4.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.4.2\bin>tasklist | findstr 19300

Comment: can you try defining the `network.host: 0.0.0.0` and try to use the default ports of ES and if it gives port already in use, then try to kill those other applications using ES default ports 9200,9300

Comment: I tried all of those and it still doesn't work. I always get the same error. It seems like any change to the elasticsearch.yml has no impact or may be there is some other problem. Is there a way to provide the port and host directly through the batch file, to override values from yml?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the port you configured is already in use.

Try starting up Elasticsearch using its default host and port configuration for both, the `transport` and `http` protocols by commenting out

```
# network.host: localhost
# http.port: 19300
```

Doing so should configure Elasticsearch to use `localhost` for both, the `transport` and `http`-protocols and the first available port in the range of 9200-9299 will be used for `http` while the first available port in the range of 9300-9399 will be used for `transport`.

BTW: Rather than specifying `localhost` you could/should use the special value "_local_" (see [Elasticsearch Reference: Network Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html))

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I started out with the default settings and it was giving me the same "already in use" error. That is when I tried to use different ports, but none of them worked either. I also tried the special "_local_" value and does not help either. I assume something else must be going wrong, hence I reached out to this community. It is my first time using elasticsearch, and I couldn't find anything on google which would help.

Comment: I think the issue might be rooted in your Windows system/network configuration, but someone else need to help out here. Sorry.